# Android application design starting point

Tags: android, performance, android-widget, android-preferences

I have just starting learning Android development. I am familiar with the Java and Adobe Flex UI. I have basic design curiosity regarding the android development.

1. What could be the ideal design to develop the app. (Lets say, I have 4-6 different tab)
   I have all the wire-frame available. which could be my starting point.
2. I wanted to use JSON and mongoDB for connectivity purpose ?
3. Is there any framework available for android development (MVC) ?
4. Generalized functionalists nice to have. eg. Email or updates for the application to notify.

I am currently going through the tutorial but thats not really helpful in terms of designing the whole application.

Please help me.

thanks,

Comment: http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android
http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html

These might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you first just need to take some time and have a good read on Google's own sites.
http://developer.android.com/index.html

Another good place for tutorials is 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/

1. There is no ideal design. Your starting point, is the site above.
2. Communication between your app and a server is mostly done by JSON or XML. You can't directly access remote databases (Maybe you can with some tricks, but you don't want to.)
3. Android is a framework, and it is based on MVC.
4. No idea what you're even asking here.

Good luck and try to make any future questions a lot more specific to programming problems.